# Write http interceptor as class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm having trouble writing an angular http interceptor in plain TypeScript. The code I'm trying to convert is the following:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

    var interceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q', 'httpBuffer', function ($rootScope, $q, httpBuffer) {
        function success(response) {
            return response;
        }

        function error(response) {
            if (response.status === 401 && !response.config.ignoreAuthModule) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                httpBuffer.append(response.config, deferred);
                $rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth-loginRequired', response);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
            // otherwise, default behaviour
            return $q.reject(response);
        }

        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(success, error);
        };

    }];
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
}])
```

The first parts are clear, write a class with a constructor that takes the three dependencies `$rootScope`, `$q` and `httpBuffer`. Also write two private methods `success` and `response`.

```
class MyInterceptorClass {
    constructor(private $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, private $q: ng.IQService, private httpBuffer: HttpBuffer) {
    }

    private success(response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any> {
        return response;
    }

    private error(response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any> {
        if (response.status == 401 && !((<any>response.config).ignoreAuthModule)) {
            var deferred = this.$q.defer();
            this.httpBuffer.append(response.config, deferred);
            this.$rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth-loginRequired', response);

            return deferred.promise;
        }

        // Otherwise, default behavior
        return this.$q.reject(response);
    }
}
```

Also the registration of the interceptor should be clear:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', ($httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider)=> {
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(['$rootScope', '$q', 'httpBuffer', MyInterceptorClass]);
}]);
```

What I am having trouble with is the last part of the original JavaScript, the return value of an anonymous function. How would I create this in TypeScript? As far as I understood this would be a nameless method in TypeScript, but this is not possible.

Answer (score 6):

The config settings are as follows

```
    .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(AuthenticationInterceptor.Factory);
    }])
```

and your actual class should look as follows

```
module Common.Security {
'use strict';

export class AuthenticationInterceptor {

    public static Factory($q: ng.IQService) {
        return new AuthenticationInterceptor($q);
    }

    constructor(private $q: ng.IQService) {
    }

    //Method name should be exactly "response" - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
    public response(response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response || this.$q.when(response);
    }

    public responseError(rejection) {
        console.log(rejection.status);
        if (rejection.status === 401) {
        }
        // Otherwise, default behavior
        return this.$q.reject(rejection);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing issue in this code. Getting error for $q. It shows undefined.
Also, could you explain how this works? I mean when this will be invoked and how instance is created. I am pretty new to angular and Typescripts

Comment: this will not work see the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211692/typescript-interceptor-in-angularjs

Comment: @Abhijeet How do you make the Factory() declaration minification-safe?

Answer (score 6):

this is  how i write httpinterceptor as a class

```
module services {

export class ErrorHttpInterceptor {
    public $log:ng.ILogService;
    public $injector:ng.auto.IInjectorService;

    public responseError = (_rejection)=>{
       //handle error here
    };
    public request = (config)=>{
        config.withCredentials = true;
        return config;
    };
    public requestError = (rejection)=>{
        var $q:ng.IQService = this.$injector.get("$q");
        this.$log.log("requestError", rejection);
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    };
    static $inject = ['$injector', '$rootScope', '$q', '$window'];
    constructor($injector:ng.auto.IInjectorService, public $rootScope, public $q, public $window){
        this.$log = $injector.get('$log');
        this.$injector = $injector;
    }
  }
}
```

to register

```
 var app =angular.module('foo',[]);
 app.config(['$httpProvider', (_$httpProvider:ng.IHttpProvider)=>{
    _$httpProvider.interceptors.push('ErrorHttpInterceptor');

}]);
```

Comment: How do you register such interceptors? What parameters do you pass to `$httpProvider.interceptors.push(...);`?

Comment: How would this work? I have the impression that when we pass a string in `interceptors`, angular requires that a service be registered with that name using `module.factory(...)`.

Comment: Hi, I noticed that none of the solutions provided include any types. Is this best practice? Or is there some type that the functions should return? I had my response returning ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>, which worked if I just wanted to return the response, but type clashed when I tried to return a rejection. Removing the types fixes it ... but it really seems like we should be using some kind of type.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do:
public response = (response) => {}

public responseError = (rejection) => { }

Because in other way your 'this' will be undefined.
To understand why you need this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Answer (score 4):

The config settings are as follows

```
    .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(AuthenticationInterceptor.Factory);
    }])
```

and your actual class should look as follows

```
module Common {
'use strict';

export class AuthenticationInterceptor {

    private static _instance: AuthenticationInterceptor;

    public static Factory($q: ng.IQService) {
        AuthenticationInterceptor._instance = new AuthenticationInterceptor($q);

        return AuthenticationInterceptor._instance;
    }

    constructor(private $q: ng.IQService) {
    }

    //Method name should be exactly "response" - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
    public response(response) {
        var self = Common.AuthenticationInterceptor._instance;

        console.log(response);
        return response || self.$q.when(response);
    }

    public responseError(rejection) {
        var self = Common.AuthenticationInterceptor._instance;

        console.log(rejection.status);
        if (rejection.status === 401) {
        }

        // Otherwise, default behavior
        return self.$q.reject(rejection);
    }
}
```

It is necessary to get the instance of the class with the full namespace because when receiving a callback from Angular '***this***' is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was also having the problem that 'this' was always undefined. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Register it by name : `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptorClass');`

And then make sure you class is also registerd as a service :

`yourApp.service('myInterceptorClass',MyInterceptorClass)`

Comment: That doesn't help my question on how to implement the last anonymous method.