# TypeScript interceptor in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, typescript, this

I'm having problems setting up a request interceptor in AngularJS using TypeScript

The following snippet works, not working variant is commented out. No matter what I inject in the constructor the local variables are undefined in the `request` method.

```
module Services
{
    export class AuthInterceptor
    {
        public static Factory(TokenService: Services.ITokenService)
        {
            return new AuthInterceptor(TokenService);
        }

        constructor(private TokenService: Services.ITokenService)
        {
            this.request = (config: ng.IRequestConfig) =>
            {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if(this.TokenService.IsAuthorised())
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + this.TokenService.Token;
                return config;
            };
        }

        public request: (config: ng.IRequestConfig)=>ng.IRequestConfig;

/* THIS IS NOT WORKING

        public request(config)
        {
                    // this.TokenService is undefined here as well as $window or $q which I tried to inject
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if(this.TokenService.Token != "")
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + this.TokenService.Token;
            return config;
        }
*/

    }
}

angular.module("Services")
    .config(($httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider)=>
    {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(Services.AuthInterceptor.Factory);
    });
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is because of the wrong `this`. Solution:

```
    public request = (config) =>
    {
                // this.TokenService is undefined here as well as $window or $q which I tried to inject
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        if(this.TokenService.Token != "")
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + this.TokenService.Token;
        return config;
    }
```

To understand why you need this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!
So, angular breaks my this probably by storing the function in the local variable and then calling it? I got a feeling it's gonna be a loooong way from C# goodness for me :)

Comment: Well, after 4 hours of research and head scratching.. this has saved me. Thank you very much. I have now found `_this` explained well in the TS specification too, http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf

Comment: The explanation is easy. There is a different in invocation of the method. Most of people expect that when you define a service with interceptor methods, they will be invoked in a way   myObj.request(<arguments...>). Unfortunately angular doesn't know that the method is a part of an object and it only takes a method and run without context. ie.  var rMethod= myObj.request;  rMethod(<arguments>).  To fix it you need to define method as a lambdas to force proper object context. This is exactly what is explain in a YT link.