# Registering AngularJs directives implemented as Typescript classes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have several Directives which are very similar in some regard, but very different in others. To reduce the amount of duplicate code inheritance can be used, however I have not yet figured out how to instantiate a directive Class.

Here is what I have tryed:

```
/// <reference path='../_all.ts' />

module app.directives {
  'use strict';

  export class myDirective implements ng.IDirective
  {

    private margin = {top: 70, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 55};
    private padding = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10};

    public restrict = 'A';
    public $scope = {
      regulationdata: "=",
      title: "="
    };

    constructor(private $window) {}

    public link($scope, element: JQuery, attr: ng.IAttributes)
    {

      // Browser onresize event
      this.$window.onresize = function () {  // TypeError: Cannot read property '$window' of undefined
        $scope.$apply();
      };

      // lots of application specific code.
    }
  }
  /** Register directive */
  angular.module('app').directive('myDirective',['$window', ($window) => { return new myDirective($window); } );


}
```

The error I receive is: `TypeError: Cannot read property '$window' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be a problem with the scope of variables within javasript.Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23214952/1696578) answer. This contains the answer described below and has a very nice explanation.

The problem is, that the `this` pointer in the method `link` is not set as expected. Just try to implement the link function as lambda function, so typescript take care of setting the this pointer correctly.

Just compare the following results:

```js
export class Test {
    private property: string;
    public link() {
        this.property;
    }
}

export class Test2 {
    private property: string;
    public link = () => {
        this.property;
    }
}
```

```js
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    var Test = (function () {
        function Test() {
        }
        Test.prototype.link = function () {
            this.property;
        };
        return Test;
    })();
    exports.Test = Test;

    var Test2 = (function () {
        function Test2() {
            var _this = this;
            this.link = function () {
                _this.property;
            };
        }
        return Test2;
    })();
    exports.Test2 = Test2;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the video from the link, you added, is really good to explain the issue.