# AngularJS 1.x TypeScript (with Webpack) Interceptor issue

Tags: webpack, angular-http-interceptors, typescript2.0, angularjs-1.5

I've just started on TypeScript, so I think it is something very silly.
I've gone through couple of dozens links but can't find exactly what is the issue that my service instance is *undefined*.
So my app structure is simple(?):
Using AngularJS 1.5 with TypeScript and Webpack.
My Main app file is as below:

```js
     // External 
    import ng = require("angular");

     // App modules
    import authIntSvc = require("./security/authInterceptorSvc");

     // Note: Can't use require as it returns object and we need function
    import localStorageHandler from "./core/localStorageCfg";
    import routingHandler from "./uiRoutes";


    export
    let ptaToolsApp = ng.module('ptaToolsApp', [
      'ngRoute', 'ngStorage',
      'ptaTools.CoreMod'
    ]);

    ptaToolsApp
      .config(routingHandler)
      .config(localStorageHandler);

    console.info("All Done...! " + new Date());

     // Add services
    import secSvc = require("./security/SecuritySvc");
    ptaToolsApp.service(secSvc.SecuritySvc.IID, secSvc.SecuritySvc);

     //import { interceptorInitiator } from "./security/authInterceptorSvc";
    ptaToolsApp.service(authIntSvc.authInterceptorSvc.IID, authIntSvc.authInterceptorSvc);

    ptaToolsApp.config(authIntSvc.interceptorInitiator);

     // Add module controlles - TODO: FInd better way 
    import {
      HomeCtrl
    }
    from "./userHome/homeCtrl";
    ptaToolsApp.controller(HomeCtrl.IID, HomeCtrl);

     // App Init --------- Run function ---------------------------------------
    function runApp(authSvc: secSvc.SecuritySvc) {
      authSvc.checkAuthData();
    }

    runApp.$inject = [secSvc.SecuritySvc.IID];

     // Run App
    ptaToolsApp.run(runApp);

     // App Init --------- Run function ---------------------------------------

     // Dummy requires, just needed for WebPack to pack it in bundle
    import coreMod = require("./core/coreModule");
    const a1 = coreMod;
    import ngRoute = require("angular-route");
    const a2 = ngRoute;
    import ngStorage = require("ngstorage");
    const a3 = ngStorage;
```

My Interceptor file is as below:

```js
    import ng = require("angular");

    import {
      appLocalStorageSvc
    }
    from "../core/appLocalStorageSvc";
    import * as secModels from "./models";

     //  implements ng.IHttpInterceptor
    export class authInterceptorSvc {

      public static readonly IID = "sec.authInterceptorSvc";

      static $inject = ['$location', '$q', appLocalStorageSvc.IID];

      constructor(private $location: ng.ILocationService, private $q: ng.IQService, private appLocalStorage: appLocalStorageSvc) {
        console.info('constructor:: ' + authInterceptorSvc.IID);
      }

      //public request(reqCfg: ng.IRequestConfig): ng.IRequestConfig {
      public request(reqCfg: any): any {
        reqCfg.headers = reqCfg.headers || {};
        // if ((this.appLocalStorage.authData) && (this.appLocalStorage.authData.isAuth === true))
        //     reqCfg.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + this.appLocalStorage.authData.oAuthToken;

        console.info("in authInterceptorSvc.request");
        console.debug(reqCfg);
        console.debug(JSON.stringify(this));

        return reqCfg;
      }

      // HTTP Rejection
      public responseError(rejection: any) {
        if (rejection.status === 401) {
          this.$location.path('/login');
          return this.$q.reject(rejection);
        }
        return this.$q.reject(rejection);
      }
    }

    export
    function interceptorInitiator($httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push(authInterceptorSvc.IID);
    }

    interceptorInitiator.$inject = ["$httpProvider"];
```

So, in above method ***request(reqCfg: any): any*** I've commented lines where I need to access local variable for appLocalStorage, I get error that "can't access property 'appLocalStorage' of *undefined*".

** I added console.log in all my service constructors (will remove later).
When I page load my app loads fine till interceptor is hit. In the request *function* my service instance is *undefined*. See the log below:

[image: Console Log]

I've highlighted the "undefined" as a result of 
    console.debug(JSON.stringify(this));

I'm wondering why my ***this*** in service is *undefined*.

Another not a big issue, I think, just practice, if you see those ***dummy*** lines in the end of main app file. Why do I need to tell webpack something that basic?

Can someone pls help?

***As my answer below the main issue is solved***
But the minor issue of putting dummy lines so that webpack bundles my files still stays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more digging, I found the answer here: (The question was almost same as mine)
[TypeScript interceptor in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211692/typescript-interceptor-in-angularjs)

So the issue was how interceptor works differently than controller or services.
You need to make it objectify (as explained in the answer in above post).

```js
public request = (config) => {
  // this.TokenService is undefined here as well as $window or $q which I tried to inject
  config.headers = config.headers || {};
  if (this.TokenService.Token != "")
    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + this.TokenService.Token;
  return config;
}
```

As shown above works fine.