# TypeScript Interceptor in Angularjs Not Working

Tags: angularjs, typescript, interceptor

My interceptor is not working (not triggered). Any error on my part? Sorry I'm still a rookie :(

```
module myApp {
export class HttpConfigurator {
    public configure(httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider) {
        console.log(httpProvider);
        console.log(httpProvider.interceptors[0]);

        httpProvider.interceptors.push([
            '$location',
            '$q',
            '$log',
            ($location: ng.ILocationService, $q: ng.IQService, $log: ng.ILogService) => {
                return promise => promise.then(
                    response => { console.log(response.status); return response; },
                    response => {
                        console.log(response.status);
                        if (response.status >= 500) {

                        }

                        if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                            $location.path('/403');
                            return $q.reject(response);
                        } else {
                            return $q.reject(response);
                        }
                    });
            }]);
    }
}
```

}

Note: Previously this is working when it was in javascript. When I converted it to typescript then the problem started.

Comment: i had made a interceptor here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798626/write-http-interceptor-as-class/26670805#26670805

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `promise` defined anywhere. Note that due to the simplicity of interceptors I just use a function + factory:

```
app.factory('appHttpInterceptor', [function () {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            if (typeof (MiniProfiler) != 'undefined') {
                var ids = response.headers()['x-miniprofiler-ids'];
                if (ids) {
                    MiniProfiler.fetchResultsExposed($.parseJSON(ids));
                }
            }

            return response;
        }
    };
}]);
```

And not use a `class`.