# AngularJs authentication using TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, authentication, typescript, jwt

I am following [this](https://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-2/) guide to implement token base authentication in my angularjs application. I am new to type script and angular. Saying that,

```
export class Routes {
    static $inject = ["$routeProvider", "$httpProvider"];
    static configureRoutes($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider, $httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(AuthInterceptor); <<--Error Here
    }
}



export class AuthInterceptor {
    constructor($rootScope, $q, authEvents) {
        return {
            responseError: function (response) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast({ 401: authEvents.notAuthenticated },[response.status], response);
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

> Error 1   Argument of type 'typeof AuthInterceptor' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'string | IHttpInterceptorFactory | (string |
>   IHttpInterceptorFactory)[]'.
>
> Type 'typeof AuthInterceptor' is not assignable to type '(string |
>   IHttpInterceptorFactory)[]'. app.routes.ts

js code I am trying to convert

```
.factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, AUTH_EVENTS) {
  return {
    responseError: function (response) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast({
        401: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated,
      }[response.status], response);
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
})
```

how would I go about to solve this error? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write http interceptor as class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798626/write-http-interceptor-as-class)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your class AuthInterceptor should impements IHttpInterceptorFactory :

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements IHttpInterceptorFactory {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a blog post show two different ways of doing this:

http://www.couchcoder.com/angular-1-interceptors-using-typescript/

#### Approach 0

```
class ApiCallInterceptor implements ng.IHttpInterceptor {
  // @ngInject
  static factory($q:ng.IQService):ApiCallInterceptor {
    return new ApiCallInterceptor($q);
  }

  constructor(private $q:ng.IQService) {
  }

  // created as instance method using arrow function (see notes)
  request = (config:ng.IRequestConfig):ng.IRequestConfig => {
    console.info('Request:', config);

    // modify config

    return config;
  };

  // created as instance method using arrow function (see notes)
  response = <T>(
      response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>
  ):ng.IPromise<T> => {
    console.info('Response:', response);

    // modify response

    return this.$q.when(response);
  };
}

let httpConfig = ($httpProvider:ng.IHttpProvider) => {
  /* push the factory function to the array of $httpProvider
   * interceptors (implements IHttpInterceptorFactory) */
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(ApiCallInterceptor.factory);
};

angular.module('app').config(httpConfig);
```

#### Approach 1

```
class HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {
    ['request', 'requestError', 'response', 'responseError']
        .forEach((method) => {
          if(this[method]) {
            this[method] = this[method].bind(this);
          }
        });
  }
}

class ApiCallInterceptor extends HttpInterceptor
                         implements ng.IHttpInterceptor {
  // @ngInject
  static factory($q:ng.IQService):ApiCallInterceptor {
    return new ApiCallInterceptor($q);
  }

  constructor(private $q:ng.IQService) {
    super();
  }

  request(config:ng.IRequestConfig):ng.IRequestConfig {
    console.info('Request:', config);

    // modify config

    return config;
  };

  response<T>(
      response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>
  ):ng.IPromise<T> {
    console.info('Response:', response);

    // modify response

    return this.$q.when(response);
  };
}

let httpConfig = ($httpProvider:ng.IHttpProvider) => {
  /* push the factory (implements IHttpInterceptorFactory) 
     to the array of $httpProvider interceptors */
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(ApiCallInterceptor.factory);
};
```