# Define a HttpInterceptor with Typescript, and make it minification-safe

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am following this SO response for defining an Angular HttpInterceptor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22405308/67038

I'm a little lost on the factory method:

```
 public static Factory($q: ng.IQService) {
    return new AuthenticationInterceptor($q);
}
```

Looks like we're expecting the $q service to be injected, but if so, that's going to break as soon as I minify.  How do I make that minification-safe?  Will the string array syntax work?

Comment: With the `"$q"` string there, the injector should inject the right service regardless of the parameter name post-mangle.

Comment: @doogle that second code block was not in the code -- it was my guess and it doesn't work.  I took it out of the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some experimentation, but I got it.

**TLDR;**

To fix it, I put this line of code AFTER, and outside of the class definition:

```
ApiCallInterceptor.Factory.$inject = ["$q"];
```

**The ugly details**

For posterity, here's what I did:

- There is a tool called ng-annotate.  If you use it as part of your build process, you won't have a
  problem.
- We aren't (and won't be) using that tool for building, so that isn't
  going to help me.

So I did this:

I installed ng-annotate and ran it as a one-off to see the javascript code that I need to have in the file:

```
npm install -g ng-annotate
```

- I temporarily added the @ngannotate marker to my factory method
- Ran that file through ng-annotate
- saw that ng-annotate produced this line of code:

  ApiCallInterceptor.Factory.$inject = ["$q"];

Cool, now I just need to find a way to get typescript to produce that line of code.

After a lot of messing around with it, I found that what you need to do is add the following line of code OUTSIDE of the class definition.  You'll get compile-time syntax errors if you try to put it inside the class definition

```
ApiCallInterceptor.Factory.$inject = ["$q"];
```